# Axiom of infinity: What is an inductive set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

This Axiom states that there exists an inductive set. But, what is the definition of an inductive set?

Comment: See [Axiom of infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity); the axiom assert s the existence of a particular set: "Such a set is sometimes called an *inductive set*."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inductive set is *exactly* a set which satisfies the definition required in the explicit formulation of the axiom. So in some places it can be more economical to define the notion of inductive sets separately and then just say that "there exists an inductive set" instead.

> **Definition.** We say that $A$ is an inductive set if $\varnothing\in A$, and whenever $x\in A$ then $x\cup\{x\}\in A$ as well.

For example $V_\omega$ is an inductive set, as well $\omega$ is the smallest inductive set (it is a subset of any inductive set).

Comment: But, then, doesn't that means that all ordinals are in $A$? Because, $\emptyset \in A$ implies $\{ \emptyset \} \in A$ implies $ 1 \in A $ implies $1 \cup \{ 1 \} \in A$,...

Comment: When do you get to conclude that $\omega \in A$? There is no $\omega - 1$.

Comment: @user83081: All the finite ordinals. Sure. Not the infinite ones. Well, not necessarily.