# Clarifying the Definition of an Inductive Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding this particular definition of an inductive set.

> **Definition.** $\exists S (\varnothing\in S\land (\forall x \in S)x\cup \{x\}\in S)$. We call a set with this property inductive.

From an already asked post I understand that the above definition is equivalent to this definition. [Axiom of infinity: What is an inductive set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926499/axiom-of-infinity-what-is-an-inductive-set)

> **Definition.** We say that $A$ is an inductive set if $\varnothing\in A$, and whenever $x\in A$ then $x\cup\{x\}\in A$ as well.

However my troubles lie with the following. I think every set has $\varnothing$ as a member. Additionally, I think that $\forall x(x \cup \{x\} = x)$. If I am interpreting the definition correctly (which I suspect I am not) and my assumptions are correct (again, dubious) wouldn't every set be inductive?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is **not** an *element* of every set, but a *subset* of every set; remind the basic difference between the relation $\in$ between element and set and the relation $\subseteq$ between sets.

Comment: Finally, $∀x(x∪{x}=x)$ is **not** true. If $x$ has e.g. three members (i.e.elements), then $x ∪ \{ x \}$ has four members : the three members of $x$ *plus* $x$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not every set has $\varnothing$ as a member. For example $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ does not have $\varnothing$ as a member. Also $\varnothing$ does not have $\varnothing$ as a member.

Additionally, $x\cup\{x\}$ is almost always not $x$ itself. It can be, under particular -- and non-standard in "everyday mathematics" -- assumptions. But $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Could you clarify please? $x\cup \{x\}=\{x,\{x\}\}$ so it is a set which contains element $x$ and element set of $x$? What if $x=\{1,2,3\}$, then  $x \cup \{x\}=\{\{1,2,3\},\{\{1,2,3\}\}\}$?

Comment: If you write down what is the formula for $x\cup\{x\}$, you'll see that $\{1,2,3\}\cup\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ is not $\{\{1,2,3\},\{\{1,2,3\}\}\}$.

Comment: oh, I made a mistake, you're right, it will be $\{1,2,3,\{1,2,3\}\}$ I think

Comment: Indeed, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not every set has $\emptyset$ as a member, but every set has $\emptyset$ as a *subset*.

That is, for any set $S$ it's not necessarily true that $\emptyset \in S$, but it is always true that $\emptyset \subseteq S$.

Comment: $\{\varnothing\}$ does have $\varnothing$ as a member. You might want to change the wording of that very first sentence. ;)

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are right. As always.

Comment: Some people might not agree with that. Those people are *wrong*. :-)