# Is this example of an inductive (sub)set correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

**Note:** It seems that the term inductive set has [varying definitions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductiveSet.html). I am not referring (I think) to the definition [used here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227114/clarifying-the-definition-of-an-inductive-set), so this question is not a duplicate of that one.

Specifically, consider the definition found on p. 12 of Dudley, *Real Analysis and Probability*:

> More generally, let $(X, <)$ be any partially ordered set. A subset $Y \subset X$ will be called *inductive* if, for every $x \in X$ such that $y \in Y$ for all $y \in X$ such that $y<x$, we have $x \in Y$.

The author then goes on to state that the set $( -\infty, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is inductive (presumably $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard partial order is meant), but:

**Question:** Is that a typo? I.e. how is $(-\infty, 0)$ inductive using the above definition? It seems like $(-\infty, 0]$ might be inductive using the above definition, but not $(- \infty, 0)$.

Either a correction of my flawed reasoning, or a sanity check that it is indeed a typo, would help.

**(Flawed) reasoning:** If we take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = (-\infty, 0)$, then seemingly $0 \in X$ is such that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $y < 0$, $ y \in (-\infty, 0)$. (That's literally the definition of that half-open interval, right?) So then seemingly by the definition of inductive set, if $(-\infty, 0)$ were inductive, we would have $0 \in (-\infty,0)$, which is obviously untrue.

However, the way the definition is worded in Dudley is very confusing to me and it seems likely that I am messing up the order of logical quantifiers and connectives to get a non-equivalent statement in my mind, in particular how I am thinking of the definition is as follows:

> *A subset $Y \subset X$ is inductive if, for all $x \in X$ such that ($y<x \implies y \in Y$)*, $x \in Y$.

(Now that I write it out my wording of the definition, in addition to most likely being wrong, is also rather opaque.) Anyway, $y <0$ clearly implies $y \in (-\infty, 0)$, hence my "reasoning" above.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the definition of inductive you wrote is the one appearing in the book (in other words, I think you copied it wrong).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I double-checked and that's how the definition is written in the version I have. If it's relevant, the section is about transfinite induction and not "classical induction". That being said, you seem to be right that it is not a standard definition; I am not sure which source/reference listed at the end of the chapter the author got it from.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't parse as an English sentence. Specifically, "such that $y\in Y$ for all $y\in Y$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh yeah I definitely agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the definition, Y subset X is inductive when
for all x in X, if (for all y < x, y in Y), then x in Y.

Implied quantifiers create confusion and though popular, should not be used.
(-oo,0) is not inductive because of 0.  (-oo,0] is inductive.

Comment: OK, so I'm not crazy? I was really confused when the author's own example didn't work.